What is the name of this movie about sleeping and death?
The thing I remember most is this saying in the film "When you fall in your dream, you die in real life". 
The protagonist is a patient in some kind of hospital. 
In the last scene (or near the end, I'm not sure), he (the patient) jumps out of the window of the hospital.

Sublime (2007), a straight to video horror movie.

...
  As the days tick by Mr. Grieves' post-operative experiences grow
  ever more bizarre until he finally realizes that he is caught inside a
  nightmare of his own creation and seems unable to escape or awaken
  back in the real world. He understands that something has gone wrong
  in his post-operative recovery which is keeping him trapped in this
  netherworld of manifestations of all of his worst fears but he
  understands neither what the problem is nor what, if anything, he can
  do to awaken from it.
  ...
  Meanwhile, back inside his own mind, George
  Grieves is in a desperate losing battle with his own manifested fears
  and decides that the only way out is to commit suicide in this
  dream-like state hoping that it will cause his real body to expire and
  free him from the interminable torment he's had to endure. He manages
  to leap from a 7th-floor window onto the concrete below, and the final
  shot is of his real-world body lying in an empty hospital room where
  it flatlines, closing its eyelids in physical death.

Movie dialogue taken http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=sublime
and paraphrased a bit:

"You know what they say...If you fall in a dream and you hit
  bottom...you'll die. You won't wake up. That's why you wake up before
  you land. It's the body-- The brain's way of protecting yourself,
  right?"  
"Maybe people who die in their sleep...they're actually dreaming of
  falling...and they land. You know, I mean, they hit bottom in the
  dream...but they really die."

